# Suggestions on structuring Asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working on a Node.js Socket Server for my messaging service and have been thinking about a way to re-organize my code to make it more understable, flow better, and most importantly—be manageable. In order to give an idea about what I think is wrong with the structure, I will present a trimmed version:

```
'use strict';

let SocketServer = require('./InitializeServer.js'); // server initialization
const MessageSender = require('./Messaging.class.js'); // import the Messanger Class
const Database = require('./SQL.js');

const conn = Database.Connection;
const SQL = Database.SQL;

/** This method is in another file and establishes a secure websocket server
 *
 *  @param {ClientObject} An object that describes everything about the client
 *  @param {ConnectionObject} An object that describes everything about the currection connection of a user, note ConnectionObject depends on ClientObject
 *  @param {req} Connection request param
 */
SocketServer.runWebSocketServer(function (ClientObject, ConnectionObject, req) {
    let poll = null;
    let _self = ClientObject.get();

    const Messanger = new MessageSender(ClientObject);
    const Chat = new SocketServer.EventDispatcher(ClientObject, ConnectionObject, {
        // these events require a "verify" key
        verify: ['status', 'actions']
    });

    // all of my handlers go here

    Chat.on('message', function (data) {
        // send out messages
    }, true);

    Chat.on('status', function (data, subtype, applyToAll) {
        // send out status messages
    }, false);

    Chat.on('typing', function (data) { 
        // "is typing" mechanism
    }, true);

    Chat.on('actions', function (action, type) {
        // set actions
    }, true);

    Chat.on('loadMore', function (start) {
        // do something here
    }, true);

    Chat.on('close', function close() {
        console.log("CLOSE CONNECTION");
    });

    // do a few more general operations below
});
```

Being that I am quite new to the Node.js environment, the repetitive section of the code throws up some flags. Extendability is typically hindered by such repetitive behavior. As a consideration, I could change the lines that repeat to follow a more object oriented approach*:

```
    Chat.on(new MessageEvent());
    Chat.on(new StatusEvent());
    Chat.on(new TypingEvent());
    Chat.on(new Actions());
    Chat.on(new LoadingEvent());
    Chat.on(new CloseEvent());
```

I am unsure if this would be the correct or best practice. What do you think?

***Note that the `.on` method does not come from any native implementation so I am very flexible**

Comment: It would clean things up a lot, you could also store those classes in other files and keep organised that way.

Comment: `Chat.on(new MessageEvent());` but `.on` seems to take two arguments `Chat.on('message', function (data) {` - I know you said you're flexible, but `Chat = new SocketServer.EventDispatcher` - is that your code? (I mean, do you decide what `new SocketServer.EventDispatcher` returns?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes that is my method. Most of the Server is built from scratch so I have pretty high flexibility in regards to design. I just love seeing what kind of creative ways other people have managed to put together similar situations

Comment: I don't see what's so repetitive about your code. All these functions are listening to different events and doing totally different things, right? Looks fine to me. You might want to post your full code, not a trimmed down version, to let us scan for abstraction possibilities.